# Tesseract OCR for Tamil not working in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, tesseract

I was using tesseract for English and Tamil. Its working perfectly in Swift for English. I can see that in tessdata folder there are lot of files for English, files like enlgish.cube.nn, english.cube.lm .. etc. But i could not find files like that for Tamil Language. All i have is this tam.traineddata file. I downloaded all files from Google Code. All files are upto date. There are some application in appStore which extracts the tamil text from image. I have no idea how people are doing this.

When i pass Tamil language text contained image to Tesseract i get errors like, there no files like tam.cube.lm, tam.cube.size..etc. I searched a lot in internet, but i could not find files for Tamil.

Please help me out here, where i can find these files.?

Code given below ->

```
import UIKit

protocol ValueFromTesseractProtocol
{
    func textRecognizedFromImage(text : String, booleanValue : Bool)
}

class TesseractModel: NSObject
{
    var delegate : ValueFromTesseractProtocol!

    //MARK: - Creating sharedInstance

    class var sharedInstance: TesseractModel {

        struct Static {

            static var sharedInstance: TesseractModel?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.sharedInstance = TesseractModel()
        }

        return Static.sharedInstance!
    }

    //MARK: - imageRecognition

    func imageRecognition(image : UIImage)
    {
        let tesseract = G8Tesseract()
        tesseract.language = "eng+tam"
        tesseract.engineMode = G8OCREngineMode.CubeOnly
        tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime = 60.0
        tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = G8PageSegmentationMode.Auto
        tesseract.image = image.g8_blackAndWhite()
        tesseract.recognize()

        if let recognizedText  = tesseract.recognizedText
        {
            // Call delegate - Pass value

            self.delegate.textRecognizedFromImage(recognizedText, booleanValue: true)
        }
        else
        {
            // Call delegate - Nil Value
            self.delegate.textRecognizedFromImage("", booleanValue: false)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have tam.traineddata in your tessdata folder?